# XDebug Helper IDE Key for Atom

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xdebug, atom-editor

I cannot find a list of IDE Keys for the Google Chrome extension XDebug Helper.  What would the IDE key for Atom be?

Comment: You probably need an Atom package with support for Xdebug, like https://atom.io/packages/php-debug

Comment: @tibsar Any will do -- as long as you can set the same in Atom. Otherwise -- just try "ATOM" one.

Comment: @DanLowe I have php-debug installed (:

Comment: @LazyOne How do I set it in Atom?

Comment: @tibsar Based on php-debug available settings it's not needed (e.g. that info is ignored) or not supported. I say -- use anything in Browser extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the php-debug Atom package, the IDE key does not matter.